# Change specific WooCommerce cart item price based on specific product IDs item count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

I have a code in WooCommerce that once you buy products with the ID:
1561, 1919, 1568, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1567
So, the second product is NIS 10.

The product on which the discount applies is only the product with ID 1561
The code works well, but as soon as I want to have multiple promotions, it doesn't work.

For example:
If you buy two products then I want the customer to be able to get product 1561 twice for NIS 10
If you buy five products, then I want the customer to be able to receive five times the product 1561 for NIS 10
And so on...

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_second_item_price', 10, 1);

function change_second_item_price($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    $discounted_product_id = 1561;
    $new_regular_price = 10; // NIS 10

    // Initialize count for the target products
    $target_product_count = 0;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if the product is one of the target products
        if (in_array($product_id, array(1561, 1919, 1568, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1567))) {
            $target_product_count += $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Check if it's the discounted product and change the regular price
            if ($product_id == $discounted_product_id && $target_product_count >= 2) {
                $cart_item['data']->set_regular_price($new_regular_price);
                $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_regular_price); // Also set the current price to the regular price
                break; // Stop the loop after changing the regular price for the second item of the discounted product
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first calculate the amount of max discounted product count, and then set the price for the appropriate product:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_second_item_price', 10, 1);

function change_second_item_price($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    $discounted_product_id = 1561;
    $new_regular_price = 10; // NIS 10

    // Initialize count for the target products
    $target_product_count = 0;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if the product is one of the target products
        if (in_array($product_id, array(1561, 1919, 1568, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1567))) {
            $target_product_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    // Loop through cart items again, to find the discounted product
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

            // Check if it's the discounted product and change the regular price
        if ($product_id == $discounted_product_id && $target_product_count >= $cart_item['quantity']) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_regular_price($new_regular_price);
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_regular_price); // Also set the current price to the regular price
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this allows customers to always buy 1561 for NIS 10. I think that's your intention, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, that's not my intention
I need the price to be NIS 10, only in pairs each time.
The sale is "the second product for NIS 10"

When all products are considered as a quantity on sale
But the discount can only apply to 1561
If you buy 2 products, then the customer gets 2 times the 1561 for NIS 10
If you buy one product, then the customer gets 1561 for NIS 10 once

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to define a new price variable.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_second_item_price', 10, 1);

function change_second_item_price($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    $discounted_product_id = 1561;
    $new_regular_price = 10; // NIS 10

    // Initialize count for the target products
    $target_product_count = 0;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Check if the product is one of the target products
        if (in_array($product_id, array(1561, 1919, 1568, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1567))) {
            $target_product_count += $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Check if it's the discounted product and change the regular price
            if ($product_id == $discounted_product_id && $target_product_count >= 2) {

            // Define new price variable
                $new_regular_price_multiplier = $new_regular_price * $target_product_count;

                $cart_item['data']->set_regular_price($new_regular_price_multiplier);
                $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_regular_price_multiplier); // Also set the current price to the regular price
                break; // Stop the loop after changing the regular price for the second item of the discounted product
            }
        }
    }
}
```